# What is my serverSessionSecrect() function actually doing?

Tags: reactjs, session-cookies, middleware

I am setting up a new application and am using some boilerplate code to manage sessions and encrypt passwords.  There is one particular function that I just can't figure out.

I've tried following the code but I am still unable to determine what is going on.

```
const serverSessionSecret = () => {
  if (!process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET ||
      process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET.length < 8 ||
      process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET === warnings.exampleBadSecret) {
    // Warning if user doesn't have a good secret
    console.log(warnings.badSecret);
  }

  return process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET;
};

module.exports = cookieSession({
  secret: serverSessionSecret() || 'secret', // please set this in your .env file
  key: 'user', // this is the name of the req.variable. 'user' is convention, but not required
  resave: 'false',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxage: 60000, secure: false },
});
```

The function references a `.env` file, which I have not created.  This explains why I always get a 'Bad Secret' `console.log`. It appears that the `serverSessionSecret` function is just testing if `process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET` meets a minimum security requirement, but what is the purpose of this.

What is the difference if I have a `.env` or not?

Comment: where is cookieSession called?

Comment: const cookieSession = require('cookie-session'); is being called at the top of this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.env` is a way to access the environment variables where the script is executing.

This allows you to inject different variables into your code, depending on where it's being ran. Environment variables can either be exported to where the code is ran (`export newEnv = NewEnvVar` for example), or exist in an `.env` file.

Look at comments for each line:

```
const serverSessionSecret = () => {
  if (!process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET || 
         // Send warning if SERVER_SESSION_SECRET does NOT exit? Or...
      process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET.length < 8 ||
         // Send warning if it less than 8 characters. Or...
      process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET === warnings.exampleBadSecret
         // Send warning if the secret matches a predefined bad example
  ) {
    // Warning if user doesn't have a good secret
    console.log(warnings.badSecret);
  }

     /* If none of the above conditions are met,
     *   a console.log warning message does not get sent.
     */

  return process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET;
     // This returns the Secret or Undefined if it does not exist.
};
```

Then in your exports:

```
module.exports = cookieSession({
  secret: serverSessionSecret() || 'secret', // please set this in your .env file
     // secret will equal your 'process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET' environment
     // variable, but if it is not defined, it will equal 'secret'
  key: 'user', // this is the name of the req.variable. 'user' is convention, but not required
  resave: 'false',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxage: 60000, secure: false },
});
```

---

To summarize, `serverSessionSecret()` is only returning a string in this case. Either `secret` or what is set in your environment variables.

It looks like you are using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session

In which case, when you are configuring the cookie session with a `secret`, their documentation shows:

> secret
>
> A string which will be used as single key if keys is not provided.
>
> keys
>
> The list of keys to use to sign & verify cookie values. Set cookies are always signed with keys[0], while the other keys are valid for verification, allowing for key rotation.

In your case, `process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET` or `secret` is being used to sign & verfiy the cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the response Oli.  I understand how .env files work to secure variables.  I am just uncertain what the process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET is doing in this particular case.  What is the secret being used for?

Comment: No worries. In the code you provided above `process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET` is not yet being used.

It is just being exported within `cookieSession`. You should find where this is being imported, and how `serverSessionSecret()` is being used with this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how this would be used within the `cookie-session` library

Comment: Thanks again Oli,  The only place `cookieSession ` is being imported is in this very component.  And the only place this component is imported is in my `server.js` file.  This file just imports and calls `express().use(sessionMiddleware)`.  (sessionMiddleware is the name of the component containing the cookieSession).

Comment: That's fine. So express is using the cookie session you have configured here. `secret` is used by the library to sign the cookie - it makes sense that you have a warning message if a weak secret is being set. I have updated my answer to explain how the library is using `secret` that you are setting.

Comment: Thanks, Oli.  I think I understand now.  So this secret is being used as a method to ensure that the stored session cookies actually belong to the user that is logged in.

Comment: Essentially yes. I don't know the science behind it, but I believe the secret is used to generate a hash, which is used to verify the cookie hasn't been tampered with on the client side. Probably reading the specific documentation on the library would yield a better insight!